# Probability of not having an accident

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 1000 drivers, out of which 20 are more likely to have an accident. Given that those 20 people might have an accident with probability of 0.8 and people that do obey the law on the road might have an accident with probability of 0.2. Assuming that random driver did not have an accident what is the probability that he will not have an accident next year?

I think i should use total probability formula, but how to use it? I need help only with writing down this formula.

Comment: The odds by which $1$ random driver will have an accident will be either $0.8$ if he belongs to the twenty losers ones, or $0.2$ if he belongs to the other group. Assuming he didn't have an accident, no one can state he won't have one in the next year.. but either that he will. Could be $0.212$?

Comment: It depends on many things. Is it possible for an individual to move between the groups? That is to get better if one is ill and careless or to get worse if one is healthy and careful? Unless we know that, then we can not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(\text{having an accident})=$$
$$=P(\text{having an accident}\cap\text{being a bad guy})+P(\text{having an accident}\cap\text{being a good guy})=$$
$$=P(\text{having an accident}\mid\text{being a bad guy})P(\text{being a bad guy})+P(\text{having an accident}\mid\text{being a good guy})P(\text{being a good guy})=$$
$$=\frac8{10}\frac{20}{1000}+\frac2{10}\frac{980}{1000}=\frac{53}{250}\approx\frac15,$$

a little high to my taste.

Here I've assumed that if somebody was a good/bad guy last year will not change this year.

Comment: Yes obviously accident in one year is independent from the other.